# Salvar uma imagem do ImagemView no Postgres

Tags: java, android, postgresql, android-layout

Ola, eu estou fazendo uma tela onde o usuário tira foto do erro e manda no nosso programa.

A rotina carrega a imagem tanto da Câmera quanto da Galeria e coloco no ImageView, nessa parte ocorre tudo bem, mas em seguida se o usuário quiser ele pode salvar a foto ou trocar, e o problema está em salvar a imagem no banco de dados Postgresql.

Eu fiz a rotina para salvar mas parece que ele salva apenas o apontamento de memória não os bytes da imagem, no banco fica salvo apenas 6 caracteres de que me parece ser o apontamento da imagem.

Desde já, obrigado pela ajuda.

//rotina para converter imagem carregada no imagemview em bytes

```
public byte[] convertImageViewToByteArray(ImageView image){
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
```

//tabela, ge_campo arquivo vai receber a imagem

```
CREATE TABLE public.tb_ged
(
  ge_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tb_ged_ge_id_seq'::regclass),
  ge_tabela character varying NOT NULL,
  ge_idtabela integer NOT NULL,
  ge_descricao character varying NOT NULL,
  ge_observ character varying,
  ge_arquivo bytea,
  ge_deletado character varying(1),
  ge_tamanho integer,
  CONSTRAINT tb_ged_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ge_id)
)
```

//monto o sql e dou o insert no banco

```
        Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();

        byte[] bImagem = convertImageViewToByteArray(img_sl_erro);
        arquivo.ge_tabela       = "tb_funcionario";
        arquivo.ge_idtabela     = 11;
        arquivo.ge_descricao    = "imagem atendimento";
        arquivo.ge_observ       = "";
        arquivo.ge_arquivo      = bImagem;
        arquivo.ge_tamanho      = bImagem.length;

    sql =
                    "insert into "+ Arquivo.table+"("+
                            Arquivo.FIELD2+", "+
                            Arquivo.FIELD3+", "+
                            Arquivo.FIELD6+", "+
                            Arquivo.FIELD7+", "+
                            Arquivo.FIELD8+", "+
                            Arquivo.FIELD11 +
                    ") values ("+
                            "'"+ arquivo.ge_tabela+"', "+
                            arquivo.ge_idtabela+", "+
                            "'"+ arquivo.ge_descricao+"', "+
                            "'"+ arquivo.ge_observ+"', "+
                            "'"+ arquivo.ge_arquivo+"', "+
                            arquivo.ge_tamanho+
                    ")";

    @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {

            try{
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();

                try{


                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Constantes.db_url_evolucao, Constantes.dg_usuario, Constantes.dg_senha);

                    //Utils.log(params[0]);
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(params[0]);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    preparedStatement.close();

                    return SUCESS;
                }catch(Exception erro){
                    log("POSTGRES Erro #2: "+erro);
                    message(context, "POSTGRES Erro #2: "+erro);
                    return ERROR;
                }
            }catch(Exception erro){
                log("POSTGRES Erro #1: "+erro);
                message(context, "POSTGRES Erro #2: "+erro);
                return ERROR;
            }
        }
```

Comment: vou testar desse jeito e depois te retorno, obrigado

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, deu certo!!!!! Usei o preparedStatement.setBytes(7, arquivo.ge_arquivo); pode converter seu comentário como resposta para eu marcar?